# How to fix node_modules/@types/systemjs/index.d.ts (333,13) of Angular 2 error?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, systemjs

I have cloned an angular 2 project and installed all requirements but when running the `ng serve` command I have a node_module error:

```
node_modules/@types/systemjs/index.d.ts (333,13): Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'System' must be of type 'any', but here h as type 'System'.
```

In my `package.json`, I have `"@types/systemjs": "^0.19.32",`. Is it something to do with compatibility? How can I fix such error? Thank you.

Comment: Try to remove `@types/systemjs` from your package.json

Comment: Or search for `declare var System` in your project. It seems, that you have `declare var System: any` code in project

Answer (score 0):

Look for the last update for **systemjs** and install it via npm, change the version in the **package.json**, then remove **node_modules** folder and type `sudo npm install`.